# Lamda function invocation ends before resolving the promise

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, promise, request, multipartform-data

I have the following code to read a file from a URL and then upload it to another destination:

```js
import request from 'request';
import FormData from 'form-data';

export const handler = async (event, context) => {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const form = new FormData();
    console.log('Streaming ...');
    form.append('file', request('https://cdn.mysite.com/video.mp4'));
    console.log('Uploading ...');
    // Invocation ends here!
    form.submit('https://www.someapi.com/upload', (error, response) => {
      if (error) reject(error);
      let body = '';
      response.on('data', chunk => {
        console.log('Receiving response ...');
        body += chunk.toString()
      });
      response.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Done ...');
        resolve(JSON.parse(body))
      });
      response.resume();
    });
  });
};
```

Running this code locally works fine, but when I deploy and run it on AWS Lambda it ends before submitting the form. I tried to remove the Promise and run the code inside it but got the same result!

I don't know if it starts the submission or not, but the last thing I see on the cloud logs is `Uploading ...`, and the invocation ends after it immediately.

How to make the Lamda function waits until the promise is resolved?

Comment: You aren't returning the promise. I don't think the Lambda runtime knows what it needs to `await` since you haven't returned anything for it to wait on.

Comment: Do you mean using `then`?

Comment: No I mean using `return`. You need to return the promise, or you need to await it inside the handler.

Comment: It worked when I removed the `async` and the `Promise` from the code. I will add the solutions down. Many thanks @MarkB for your help!

Comment: Your response.on("data" response.on("end" and collection of strings can be simplified to `await response.toArray()` if your Node is relatively modern (and save the `new Promise` by doing that + calling `util.promisify` on form.submit which takes a callback function and returns a promise one)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using a **non-async handler**, and removing the promise from the code. Here's a working copy of my code:

```js
import request from 'request';
import FormData from 'form-data';

export const handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const form = new FormData();
  console.log('Streaming ...');
  form.append('file', request('https://cdn.mysite.com/video.mp4'));
  console.log('Uploading ...');
  form.submit( 'https://www.someapi.com/upload', (error, response) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    let body = '';
    response.on('data', chunk => body += chunk.toString());
    response.on('end', () => {
      console.log('Done ...');
      callback(null, JSON.parse(body));
    });
    response.resume();
  });
};
```

In this case, the Lambda function will wait for the `callback` to terminate, based on the [**AWS Lambda function handler in Node.js**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html) documentation.

### Update

Another solution using the `https` native module of Nodejs instead of the deprecated `request` library:

```js
import https from 'https';
import FormData from 'form-data';

export const handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const form = new FormData();
  console.log('Streaming ...');
  https.get('https://cdn.mysite.com/video.mp4', response => {
    form.append('file', response);
    console.log('Uploading ...');
    form.submit('https://www.someapi.com/upload', (error, response) => {
        if (error) callback(error);
        let body = '';
        response.on('data', chunk => body += chunk.toString());
        response.on('end', () => {
          console.log('Done ...');
          callback(null, JSON.parse(body));
        });
        response.resume();
      }
    );
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is missing a `return` statement as mentioned by Mark in the comments:

```js
import request from 'request';
import FormData from 'form-data';

export const handler = async (event, context) => {
  // --- here, promises work with return values
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   // ... rest of your code
  });
};
```

But can be simplified extensively (assuming modern Node.js) without any nesting:

```js
import request from 'request';
import FormData from 'form-data';
import { promisify } from 'util';

export const handler = async (event, context) => {
    const form = new FormData();
    console.log('Streaming ...');
    form.append('file', request('https://cdn.mysite.com/video.mp4'));
    console.log('Uploading ...');
    // Invocation ends here!
    await promisify(cb => form.submit('https://www.someapi.com/upload', cb))()
    const bodyParts = await response.toArray();
    return response.map(x => x.toString()).join('');
};
```

In general you almost never need to wrap things in `new Promise` in code.

Comment: That's right! I don't know why I went with the promise option. And thank you for the `await response.toArray()` suggestion!

Comment: @JafarAbazeed sure, if you find this answer useful consider upvoting it. I get nothing (I opened this answer as community wiki) but other users will see it when they open your question.